# Tomcat 8 nedds restart after ClassNotFoundException is thrown

Tags: java, tomcat, weblogic, tomcat8

My Tomcat frontend server communicates with my WebLogic backend server via Hessian protocol. When the Rollback exception is thrown by WebLogic (the exception itself is the WebLogic extension of JTA Rollback exception) than it causes Tomcat to go down (not only frontend application but also others deployed  apps on this Tomcat). I know that "weblogic.transaction.RollbackException" is not on Tomcat's classpath but shouldn't just that one webapp go down?  Is it a way to prevent it from happening ?

```
14:45:11.507 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] WARN  c.c.hessian.io.SerializerFactory - Hessian/Burlap: 'weblogic.transaction.RollbackException' is an unknown class in WebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@bebdb06
:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.transaction.RollbackException
14:45:11.507 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] WARN  c.c.hessian.io.SerializerFactory - Hessian/Burlap: 'weblogic.transaction.RollbackException' is an unknown class in WebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@bebdb06
:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.transaction.RollbackException
14:45:11.508 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] WARN  c.c.hessian.io.SerializerFactory - Hessian/Burlap: 'weblogic.transaction.internal.AppSetRollbackOnlyException' is an unknown class in WebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@bebdb06
:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.transaction.internal.AppSetRollbackOnlyException
14:45:11.517 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] ERROR c.t.w.c.GlobalExceptionHandler - Error code 20160504144511516
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have weblogic.transaction.RollbackException on the tomcat classpath